# Why are some Android themes slower than others?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-3.0-honeycomb, horizontalscrollview

I'm working on an application for Honeycomb and have tried out various themes for it, including the default Holo theme, Holo Light and Holo Wallpaper. My layout is using a HorizontalScrollView with ImageViews and I've found that it gets a bit laggy when using the default Holo and Holo Light themes. It's super fluid with the Holo Wallpaper theme, though, despite it including a bitmap background.

I've even tried making my own theme with a bitmap background, but that just slows down everything even more.

I'd like to have a speedy ScrollView, so if anyone has an answer to why some are faster than others, please let us know :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are drawing too many layers. The Holo theme, especially when hardware accelerated, has a default background image on the window. Try to remove it if it's not visible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I wouldn't say I've got too many layers (One LinearLayout to hold two TextViews and a HorizontalScrollView, and that's it).

You mention hardware acceleration - is it something that can be disabled or enabled by the developer?

Comment: Please see my answer below to find out how to enable hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like such a noob. Here's how to enable hardware acceleration in Honeycomb. Add this to your manifest file in the application tag:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```